# Rails installation failed with name-error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After running `sudo gem install rails` or `gem install rails` it fails on my ubuntu system with following message. I'm new to ruby and unable to figure it out.

```
$ sudo gem install rails
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:50:in `<class:Specification>': undefined method `rubyforge_project=' for class `Gem::Specification' (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /snap/ruby/201/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems.rb:1348:in `require'
    from /snap/ruby/201/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems.rb:1348:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

Comment: I have installed ruby using command sudo apt-get install ruby --classic as rbenv was failing with errors

Comment: to be honest, resolving that rbenv thing seems easier and it's the right thing to do. rbenv never ever failed on me with various versions of ubuntu. Is it perhaps that you forgot to install `ruby-build`?

Comment: I'll try now  any command you can give me here

Comment: Or you could just follow rbenv installation guide and post the error you get.